# Trying to extract a specific JSON key, app keep crashing

Tags: android, json

I am trying to follow a tutorial on YT on extracting a specific value from a key, I am trying to work with a gov api.

This is the JSON output im trying to work with: [here](https://pastebin.com/ede9enGy)

I am trying to edit a TextView, named "num" and make it the value of the key "mispar_rechev" on that JSON.

This is my code:

```
    package com.example.rechev;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public TextView num = findViewById(R.id.test_t);
    public RequestQueue mRequestQueue;


    private void parseJSON(){

        String url = "https://data.gov.il/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8fc424a7-2ecd-4180-852d-8fadd67abf20&filters={%22mispar_rechev%22:%225970065%22}";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("records");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject number = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        int carNumber = number.getInt("mispar_rechev");

                        num.setText(carNumber);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON(); // trying to call the function on start up.


    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The emulator just shows an error message saying "App keeps stopping".

Comment: Check your `Logcat` in the bottom of IDE and see the logs there. There are multiple options. You can select VERBOSE,DEBUG,ERROR etc

Comment: may be you can try `getLong` instead of `getInt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public TextView num = findViewById(R.id.test_t);
```

to

```
public TextView num;
```

Change

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON(); // trying to call the function on start up.
    }
```

To

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        num = findViewById(R.id.test_t); 
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON(); // trying to call the function on start up.
    }
```

You are trying to write things to a NULL TextView as this cannot be initialized until after `setContentView()`

You also need to change Change `num.setText(carNumber);` to `num.setText(String.valueOf(carNumber))`

Comment: Thank you! the app does not crash anymore, but the TextView still does not change at all, any clue as to why?

Comment: You also need to change Change `num.setText(carNumber);` to `num.setText(String.valueOf(carNumber))`

setText(intValue) exists but it's meant for using a resource ID from Strings XML. It should have crashed or thrown some exception... Changing it to a String uses the setText(stringValue) function which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Change `num.setText(carNumber)` to `num.setText(String.valueOf(carNumber))`

Answer (score -1):

in your code TRY

```
num.setText(carNumber.toString());
```